# How to return array of struct?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Function `getBets()` gives me the error: `error: Failed to decode output: Error: Unsupported or invalid type: tuple`. What am I missing?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Casino {

    struct Bet {
        address by;
        uint number;
    }

    address owner;
    Bet[] bets;

    event BetPlaced(Bet bet);

    function Casino() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function bet(uint number) {
        Bet memory bet;
        bet.by = msg.sender;
        bet.number = number;

        bets.push(bet);

        BetPlaced(bet);
    }

    function getBets() constant returns (Bet[]) {
        return bets;
    }

    function getCount() constant returns (uint length) {
        return bets.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment if I'm correct you can't return anything except an array of integers as there is no support for returning multi-dimensional data storages;

You can use an experimental library using:

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```

in the place of:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
```

This isn't available on Remix if you're using that at the moment and it's experimental so it may never be part of Solidity source: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2948

If you did want to return an array of structs you could convert the whole array to bytes and return the bytes. This would be a bit of an extreme case and I wouldn't advise it.

If you only need to access the method internally and not externally you can pass by storage e.g.

```
function getBets() internal returns (Bet[] storage _r) {
    _v = bets;
}
```

Comment: If it's not common to return an array of struct, I feel like I might just be thinking about this incorrectly. All I'm trying to do is users can add numbers to a list, and I want to show all of those numbers along with who added it.

Comment: You could construct it as a string and return just the string?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to switch your struct to another contract. This way you can return an array of addresses. I have found using structs is only useful in storing and retrieving "that" data. Contracts are better to return sets of addresses. Also, I have not used the experimental encoder, so just going off of the current solidity version.